# limit T in a generic class to types that implement some interface

Tags: dart

In dart consider the following

```
class Question<T>{
  String body;
  T answer;
}

//an interface
class IAnswer{
  String Value()=>this.toString();  
}
```

I need T to be limited to types the for example implement the interface IAnswer, is that possible without having to check if T is IAnswer and throw and exception in the Question constructor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```dart
class Question<T extends IAnswer>{
  String body;
  T answer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks same as the java way!

Comment: It's a while that I used Java. As far as I remember Java has more options.

Comment: It's basically "Bounded Type Parameters" from Java or "Upper Type Bounds" from Scala. WoW! Didn't know that Dart allow this. Looks like in couple of years Dart will be as simple as Scala I'm so excited :P